# How can I mention the name of a LaTeX command in my beamer presentation?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, presentation, beamer

I am preparing a presentation in beamer with [`gradientframe`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gradientframe) package. But it's giving me an error.

How can I write the name of the command in `\frame`?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
The gradientframe package provides a command, \gradientframe for simple and discreet 
rectangular grayscale gradient frames around objects, such as figures or tables, to set 
them apart from the surrounding text.
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Duplicate question on tex.stackexchange: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363

Comment: possible duplicate of [Environment where all formatting is ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650471/environment-where-all-formatting-is-ignored)

Answer (score 0):

As in several answers to the [linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/how-does-one-insert-a-backslash-or-a-tilde-into-latex) (thanks @Bas Swinckels), the way advised to insert a backslash `\` in the output is to use `\textbackslash` in the source.

Then, you can use (or not) just `\texttt{}` (rather than verbatim or else) to mark command names.

Finally, if you have to mention these command name(s) many times in your slides, you may want to put the above two in a `newcommand`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\mycomm}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
%\newcommand{\commgf}{\texttt{\textbackslash gradientframe}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}

    ... a command, \textbackslash gradientframe for simple ...

    or:

    ... a command, \texttt{\textbackslash gradientframe} for simple ...

    or, better:

    ... a command, \mycomm{gradientframe} for simple ...
    %... a command, \commgf{} for simple ...
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code gives you:

[image: screenshot of the slide]

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650471/environment-where-all-formatting-is-ignored/31950214#31950214