# Environment where all formatting is ignored

Tags: latex

Does there exist a command in LaTeX, such that all that I write within that environment is showed as it is?

For instance when I want to make a guide on how to use commands in LaTeX I'm interested in writing something like:

```
In order to write $\cap$, you use the command \cap.
```

But this will return an error because (the last) `\cap` isn't in the correct environment. So what can I do to make LaTeX ignore the command and just show the text?

I have tried with `\mbox{\cap}`, which does not work, I am also aware that I can do `$\backslash$cap`, but this is quite a problem specific solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the default LaTeX `\verb` (with a choice of paired delimiters) or [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) (which supports bracketed arguments using `\lstinline`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

In order to write~$\cap$, you use the command~\verb|\cap|.

In order to write~$\cap$, you use the command~\lstinline{\cap}.

\end{document}
```

There are other options as well, but this seems to suit your needs. Of course, if you want to use something like `\function` instead of `\lstinline`, then add

```
\let\function\lstinline
```

after loading the `listings` package.

Comment: Good, `\lstinline` is probably the best option!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}
%\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

In order to write \verb|$\cap$|, you use the command \texttt{\textbackslash cap}.

\end{document}
```

Notice that, to use inline `verb`, you don't even need the package [`verbatim`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim).

Furthermore, `\textbackslash` must be used here, instead of `$\backslash$`.

**Addendum:**

Reading your comment below, I think something like the following may be useful:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{article}

\newcommand{\mycomm}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}

\begin{document}

In order to write $\cap$, you use the command \mycomm{cap}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not exactly solve my problem. The first part of the sentence is not a problem (In order to write $\cap$, you use the command) it is the very last part. Where I am interested in a function i can simply put around \cap, in order for latex to just write \cap. I could use all other commands as example as well, where if i write $\alpha$ then I get the symbol alpha, but if I use the function I ask for e.g. function{\alpha}, then when I compile it will just show \alpha.

Comment: Edited: see if this helps you properly. Sorry for not too much fantasy in naming commands...